# List the game date once and the total amount of merchandise sold at each game, include the total amount in a separate row

Tags: mysql, database

Here is my code but it does not give me the desire results. can someone tell me where I went wrong.

```
select  gameDate as Game, format(SUM(mPrice * mquantity), 'c') as Total from  salesTransaction s join game g on g.gameId = s.gameId join merchandise m on m.mId = s.mID GROUP by gameDate
```

salesTransaction

| stid | paymentmethod | mquantity | mId | spid | gameid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 20 | credit card | 2 | 12 | 34 | 1 |
| 121 | credit card | 1 | 15 | 34 | 1 |
| 122 | credit card | 2 | 12 | 35 | 1 |
| 123 | credit card | 3 | 13 | 34 | 1 |
| 124 | cash | 5 | 14 | 35 | 2 |
| 125 | cash | 1 | 12 | 35 | 2 |

Game

| gameid | gameDate | gameOpponent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07-03-2020 | Loomers |
| 2 | 14-03-2020 | Zoomers |

Merchandise

| mid | mType | mPrice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | Jersy | $100.00 |
| 12 | Souvenir Ball | $40.00 |
| 13 | Water bottle | $15.00 |
| 14 | T-shirt | $25.00 |
| 15 | Autographed picture | $75.00 |

Expected results

| Games | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-07 | $400.00 |
| 2020-03-14 | $165.00 |
| All Merchandise | $565.00 |

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql If you just need  the general total you could try using an union

```
select  date_format(g.gameDate,'%d-%m-%Y)' as Game
    , SUM(mPrice * mquantity) as Total 
from  salesTransaction s 
join game g on g.gameId = s.gameId 
join merchandise m on m.mId = s.mID 
GROUP by gameDate
union 
select  'All Merchandise'
    , SUM(mPrice * mquantity)
from  salesTransaction s 
join game g on g.gameId = s.gameId 
join merchandise m on m.mId = s.mID 
order by game
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the results did not match the expected results. link to the expected result is in the question.

Comment: you commen us less  clear then  your question  .. so try avoid image and post the sample as tabular  .. text .. and try explain the difference between my answer and you expected  result ...

Comment: I have edited the question. hope it makes sense now?

Comment: answer updated ..

Comment: Thanks for the effort ScaisEdge but the results is not same as the answer.

Comment: show me you actual result  ..  so i can eval  ho differ  ..

Comment: The last table in the question is the expected results. Thanks

Comment: sorry I'm not sure i understood your question.            here is the result after running your query 
2020-03-07 245.0000, 
2020-03-14 200.0000,
All Merchandise 445.0000

Comment: based on your data sample the result for my query should be 2020-03-07 280.0000 and not 2020-03-07 245.0000  as in your comment or  nor 2020-03-07  400.000 as oin data sample result .. so check better

Comment: I have double-checked again but the query result is not giving me the right result which is   All Merchandise = $565.00